# Mongoose ADDING/SUMING subdocument array value which is within another subdocument array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My document looks like this:

```
_id:'111'
products:[
   {
    _id:'pqr'
    nums:[
      {_id:'aaa',
      quantity:30
      },
      {_id:'bbb',
       quantity:40
      }
    ]
   }
]
```

I need to get:

(i) summation of quantity field which is inside nums subdocument which again is in products subdocument.

(ii) products array to be returned as a whole (with the calculated quantity within it AND the nums subdocument as it is)

Below is how I want my output to be like:

```
products:[
  {
   _id: 'pqr',
   nums:[
      {_id:'aaa',
      quantity:30
      },
      {_id:'bbb',
       quantity:40
      }
   ],
   quantity: 70
  }
]
```

So far, I have tried doing this

```
    Shop.aggregate([

         {$match: {'_id':'111'},

         {$unwind: "$products"},

         {$group:{
            _id : "$_id",
            nums:{$last:"$nums"},
            quatity: //I have no idea how to get this total quantity which corresponds to _id:'pqr'
          }
         }

    ])
```

Any work around on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good use case for `$reduce`:

```
Shop.aggregate([
     {$match: {'_id':'111'},
     {$unwind: "$products"},
     {$addFields:{
          "products.quantity":{
              $reduce:{
                   input: "$products.nums",
                   initialValue: 0
                   in: {$sum:["$$value","$$this.quantity"]}
              }
          }
      }}
])
```